# What stores the android thumbdata file?

Tags: android, file

On my Umidigi A5 PRO, when I delete a photo, its JPG thumbnail also gets deleted from the dcim/.thumbnails folder, but there remains a fairly large file called thumbdata. Could that thumbnail still be stored within the thumbdata file?

What does the thumbdata file actually contain?

I don't know if the jpg thumbnails that the system deleted may still have remained within the thumbdata file